# This formula's limit

Tags: limits

I'm fairly sure that this is a basic question but I'm still a bit confused.
The question I'm trying to do is:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t}-\sqrt{4-t}}
$$
I'm not sure how to sort the denominator so that I can carry on. I was thinking of rationalising it but I'm not sure that would work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by one by means of conjugate of denominator:

$$ \frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t}-\sqrt{4-t}}\cdot\overbrace{\frac{\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t}}{\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t}}}^{=1}=\frac{\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t}}2\xrightarrow[t\to0]{}\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t}}{\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t}}$$ to get
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t}-\sqrt{4-t}}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t(\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t})}{2t}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t})}{2}=2$$